# Existence of compact Hausdorff topologies

Tags: general-topology, logic, set-theory

Consider the following statement

> $(C_2)$: For every set $X$ there exists a compact Hausdorff topology on $X$.

$C_2$ is a theorem of $ZFC$, because Choice gives us a bijection between any infinite set and the successor ordinal of the cardinality of the set, and any successor ordinal is compact and Hausdorff in its order topology.

**Question:** Is $C_2$ a theorem of $ZF$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$ZF$ already proves $C_2$. Given a nonempty set $X$, pick a point $p$ in $X$ and declare a set to be open if it either does not contain $p$ or is cofinite. $ZF$ proves this topology to be compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise there was such a simple answer. This makes the original formulation of the question overly complicated so I edited it to make it more useful to the readers.

Comment: This is called "the one point compactification" of a discrete space $X \setminus \{p\}$.